# can not get all the values from arraylist in android

Tags: android, arraylist

I want to get one by one value from arraylist and set those to `TextView`, but I could not.
My code is :

```
try {
        // Getting Array of Contents
        jsonArrar = json.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTENTS);

        // looping through All Contents
        for(int i = 0; i < jsonArrar.length(); i++){
            JSONObject c = jsonArrar.getJSONObject(i);
            list = new ArrayList<String>();

            String id1=jsonArrar.getJSONObject(i).getString(TAG_ID);                

            list.add(id1);
        }

        Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator();
        builder = new StringBuilder();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            String string = iterator.next();                
            builder.append(string+"\n");

        }

        textView.setText(builder);
```

in above way i only get the last value any one is welcome for telling about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must declare the list before the loop and in the `for` loop only add the elements to it:

```
list = new ArrayList<String>();    
for(int i = 0; i < jsonArrar.length(); i++){
        JSONObject c = jsonArrar.getJSONObject(i);


        String id1=jsonArrar.getJSONObject(i).getString(TAG_ID);                

        list.add(id1);
}
```

With your approach, for every element in `jsonArrar` is declared a new list so you end up having `jsonArrar.length()` lists from which only the last one is accessible (to the others you no longer have a reference).

Comment: ok! this gives me data in `[1,2,3,4]`  fomat how to get each value from there??

Comment: isn't that what you expect to receive?